# Is the cycling of the Clockworks tied to any unit of real time?

Tags: spiral-knights

Since the snowball achievement during the Steam Gift Pile, I've been playing Spiral Knights.

One thing I've noticed is that I seem to be getting the same levels a lot, despite several things/people mentioning that the Clockworks cycle levels.

So I began to wonder, could it be because I play at around the same time every day?

Is the cycling of the Clockworks tied to any unit of real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new gate becomes available every two days. The leftmost gate becomes unavailable, and the rest are shifted to the left by one.

Regarding levels themselves, these are determined pseudorandomly. You can see which level you will encounter next based on the monitor near the next elevator, or through your Gate Map which is accessible through the Main Menu. The next level will change every 3-7 minutes, so if you want to avoid a level, or get a specific one, you can wait for it to change.

---

Sources:

(gates) http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Gate#Active_Gates

(levels) http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Gate#Level_Rotation